# Connecting to PHP NuSOAP server with Ruby Savon client

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm trying to connect to a remote SOAP service, which has been set up with the PHP NuSoap library. I'm connecting using a Ruby Savon client.

Visiting the service's WDSL address (http://example.com/api/webservice.php?wdsl) gives the following information about the end point I'm trying to use:

```
   Name: addsubscription
   Binding: webserviceBinding
   Endpoint: http://www.example.com/api/webservice.php
   SoapAction: http://www.example.com/api/webservice.php/addsubscription
   Style: rpc
   Input:
     use: encoded
     namespace:
     encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
     message: addsubscriptionRequest
     parts:
   Output:
     use: encoded
     namespace:
     encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
     message: addsubscriptionResponse
     parts:
   Namespace:
   Transport: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
   Documentation:
```

Setting up my Savon client like so:

```
client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: "http://www.example.com/api/webservice.php?wdsl")
```

and then trying to call the 'add subscription' method:

```
response = client.call(:addsubscription) do
  message my_hash_of_stuff
end
```

gives the following error in the logs -

```
Savon::UnknownOperationError: Unable to find SOAP operation: :addsubscription
Operations provided by your service: []
```

Setting up the client like so:

```
client = Savon.client do
  endpoint "http://www.example.com/api/webservice.php"
  namespace ''
end
```

and then running the same call as above raises a ***Savon::SOAPFault*** error, which I'm assuming would be due to the lack of a namespace attribute (I'm not sure how to further debug/glean information from this error)?

Based on the information above, how should I configure the Savon client to connect to this service?

**Edit:**

Setting up the client like so -

```
client = Savon.client(namespace: '', endpoint: 'http://www.example.com/api/webservice.php')
```

and then calling (with a populated message_hash var)

```
response = client.call(:addsubscription,
                     message: message_hash)
```

spits out the following error:

```
Savon::SOAPFault: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nori-2.6.0/lib/nori.rb:72:in `find_value': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/nori-2.6.0/lib/nori.rb:38:in `find'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/soap_fault.rb:24:in `to_s'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:498:in `write'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:498:in `print'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:486:in `block in eval_input'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:245:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `loop'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `catch'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:230:in `each_top_level_statement'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:485:in `eval_input'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:395:in `block in start'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:394:in `catch'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:394:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I assumed you're not *really* calling `http://www.example.com/api/webservice.php?wdsl`, do you? That's just your placeholder?

Comment: Also: If you switch on logging in your Savon client you might get better information what's going wrong. How does the WSDL looks like? What you posted is not a WSDL but some other pseudocode (?) document. I just noticed that there is a `style: rpc` in the document which hints it isn't SOAP??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on an outdated Savon version < 2.x. I recommend to upgrade to version 2.x (2.11.1 as I'm writing). The interface changed considerably with the introduction of v2.

A minimal implementation could look like this:

```
require 'savon'

WSDL = 'http://www.example.com/api/webservice.php?wdsl'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: WSDL,
                      log: true,
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true)
response = client.call(:addsubscription,
                        message: my_hash_of_stuff)
print response.to_hash
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've got 2.11.1 in use according to my Gemfile.lock and I'm pulling my information from the docs here - http://savonrb.com/version2/client.html  - I've updated the question with some more information though